# Tiptap editor focus last element present inside the content

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tiptap

The issue is when I click on the first <**p**> tag inside content of tiptap editor, it focuses the last <**p**> tag. When I click first time, otherwise working fine.

I tried with various focusing method to focus the first element but I want functionality to not focus when component is loaded.

here is my code, any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
const editor = useEditor({
extensions: [
  Document,
  StarterKit.configure({
    document: false,
    heading: {
      levels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    },
  }),
  Image,
  Strike,
  Highlight.configure({ multicolor: true }),
  Link.configure({
    openOnClick: true,
  }),
  Emoji.configure({
    emojis: [...gitHubEmojis],
    enableEmoticons: true,
    forceFallbackImages: true,
  }),
  ReactComponent,
  ImageCustomExtension,
  MentionExtension,
  MentionTipTap.configure(),
],
editorProps: {
  attributes: {
    class: `prose custom-note sm:prose lg:prose-lg xl:prose-2xl mx-auto focus:outline-none ${
      isTaskNote ? "" : "pb-32"
    }`,
  },
},

// Events
onUpdate({ editor }) {
  const json = editor.getJSON();
  debouncedUpdate(json);
},
```

});